# Deleting an object from an array on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, splice

I am trying to create my own small Twitter.

It is all working fine but I cannot find a way to delete specific tweet on click of a button. I have tried splice() but it deletes the first object of an array always.

Here is my code:

```js
var tweets = []

function postNewTweet() {

  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getDate() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getFullYear();
  var time = today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes();
  var id = tweets.length + 1;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('newTweet').value;
  var finalValue = id + ' ' + inputValue + ' ' + date + ' ' + time;
  var t = document.createTextNode(finalValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  tweets.push({
    id: id,
    content: inputValue,
    date: date + ' ' + time
  });
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById('newTweet').value = "";
  console.log(tweets);

  var buttonDelete = document.createElement("button");
  buttonDelete.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>';
  buttonDelete.onclick = deleteItem;

  function deleteItem(e) {
    var ul = document.getElementById('list');
    ul.removeChild(li);

    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var index = e.target.getAttribute('value');
      tweets.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(tweets)
    });
  }
  li.appendChild(buttonDelete);
}
```

```html
<div id='post'>
  <textarea maxlength="160" id='newTweet'></textarea>
  <button id='postIt' onclick="postNewTweet()">Post</button>
</div>

<ul id='list'>

</ul>
```

So it deletes it in HTML, but not in array correctly.

Comment: It means that index is always 0. Did you make a console.log on index to see what it returns?

Comment: The first argument of [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is the start index. `const arr = ['a', 'b']; arr.splice(1,1); console.log(arr); // ['a']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of your **deleteItem** function's body seems useless. While there are couple of ways to resolve it, I suggest the following:

```
function deleteItem(e) {
    var ul = document.getElementById('list');
    ul.removeChild(li);

    var foundIndex = tweets.findIndex(function (tweet) {
        return tweet.id == id;
    });
    if (foundIndex > -1) {
        tweets.splice(foundIndex, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thaks a lot! This works amazing. I am quite new to this, so one question.. in which case can index be -1 so we have to put:
if (foundIndex > -1) {
        tweets.splice(foundIndex, 1);
    }?

Comment: You're welcome:) If the tweet with such id can't be found in the array, the index will be -1. For example if you have removed the item already somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. If you just take the length of the array as the id you will get duplicate entries, if you delete an entry. Perhaps go to a timestamp - i just used the one you already had there but added seconds
2. You retrieve the value-attribute but for splice you need the index of the element. I just added the timestampt as an attribute to the button and used it for removal.

Probably not my best code but I hope it gives you the right hints.

```js
var tweets = []

function postNewTweet() {

  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getDate() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getFullYear();
  var time = today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() + ':' + today.getSeconds();
  var id = tweets.length + 1;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('newTweet').value;
  var finalValue = id + ' ' + inputValue + ' ' + date + ' ' + time;
  var t = document.createTextNode(finalValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  tweets.push({
    id: id,
    content: inputValue,
    date: date + ' ' + time
  });
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById('newTweet').value = "";
  console.log(tweets);

  var buttonDelete = document.createElement("button");
  buttonDelete.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-trash-alt" del-date="'+date + ' ' + time +'">del</i>';
  buttonDelete.onclick = deleteItem;

  function deleteItem(e) {
    var ul = document.getElementById('list');
    ul.removeChild(li);

    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var delDate = e.target.getAttribute('del-date');
      let index = tweets.map((item) => item.date).indexOf(delDate);
      console.log(index);
      tweets.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(tweets)
    });
  }
  li.appendChild(buttonDelete);
}
```

```html
<div id='post'>
  <textarea maxlength="160" id='newTweet'></textarea>
  <button id='postIt' onclick="postNewTweet()">Post</button>
</div>

<ul id='list'>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have access to `li` in your delete function, you have access to all the other data too. You can use them to find out the element to remove from the `tweets` array.
For example, in your current code, you can use the `id`:

```
    tweets.splice(id - 1, 1)
```

Or you can use `filter` with any of the data that you store in `tweets`.And I don't see any use for this part:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var index = e.target.getAttribute('value');
      tweets.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(tweets)
    });
```

You can just remove the tweet under the `ul.removeChild`